# XSLT 2.0 processing invalid node mixing text and cdata

Tags: xslt, cdata, xslt-2.0

I need to parse the following node:

```
  <media:keywords>keyword1,keyword2<![CDATA[keyword3]]></media:keywords>
```

into a valid string, preferably "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3" but I would settle for removing the cdata completely.

Trying to access the node gives me the text "keyword1,keyword2keyword3" and I can't tell where the CDATA begins.

original xml (simplified version of mRSS feed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <channel>
     <item>
      <media:keywords>keyword1,keyword2<![CDATA[keyword3]]></media:keywords>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

xsl (simplified):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <test>
            <xsl:variable name="items" select="/rss/channel/item"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                <xsl:variable name="mediakw" select="media:keywords"/>
                <xsl:element name="mediaKeyWords">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$mediakw"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the output:

```
<test xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"><mediaKeyWords>keyword1,keyword2keyword3</mediaKeyWords></test>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use Saxon respectively a Java implementation of an XSLT 2.0 processor then look into plugging http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ into your processing chain as that way you can have CDATA sections changed into markup the XSLT processor can then operate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XML and XSLT cannot help you here**.

**XSLT uses the INFOSET model in which there isn't anything as a "CDATA node"** and there is just a single text() node:

"keyword1,keyword2keyword3"

**The XML document needs to be corrected and a comma be inserted** between the substrings `"keyword2"` and `"keyword3"`

**One solution would be** to process the CDATA DOM node using DOM, and only then initiate the XSLT transformation.

Comment: +1 good points. I wasn't aware that DOM offers CDATASection as an optional "extended interface". I wonder what processors support that.

Comment: @LarsH: MSXML, and .NET XmlReader (NodeTypeEnumeration)

Comment: +1 For every day learn something! http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1590626202

Comment: @Dimitre and @Alejandro, here's a rabbit trail for you: since XSLT offers *some* controls over serialization of certain elements using CDATA sections on output, should we say that XSLT limits itself to the INFOSET spec regarding input and internal representation, but not with regard to output? Is there a principled reason why XSLT should be aware of CDATA on output but not on input? Granted, cdata-section-elements (output) is not guaranteed to be supported; but awareness of CDATA sections on input is not even optional. Why the asymmetry? Just curious.

Comment: @LarsH: As we all know well, XSLT operates on *trees* not on any particular lexical representation. And due to this design, XSLT operates on INFOSET instances, in which the particular lexical representation is lost.

Comment: @Dimitre: agreed, that's what we are told... so if XSLT does not operate on any particular lexical representation, why does it have so many (optional) features to control lexical representation on output? I suppose the answer is pragmatics... people often need/want to be able to control lex-rep on output. But then XSLT is not as pure Infoset as we often portray it.

Comment: @LarsH: Who said that XSLT is INFOSET?

Comment: @Dimitre, if you're referring to my phrase "XSLT is not as pure Infoset", that was a sloppy way of saying "XSLT is not as purely agnostic about information that's not in the Infoset" (as we often portray it). I thought that's what you meant by "XSLT uses the INFOSET model" and "XSLT operates on trees *not on any particular lexical representation*". I didn't mean XSLT = INFOSET, if that's what you thought I was saying. My main question is, if XSLT does not operate on any particular lexical representation, why does it have so many (optional) features to control lexical representation on output?

Comment: In other words, why is XSLT lexical-representation-agnostic on input but not on output?

Comment: @LarsH: In order to be maximally useful.

Comment: @Dimitre: quite so. But if this kind of CDATA-awareness is useful for output, is it not useful for input? This OP could argue that in order to be maximally useful, XSLT should go beyond Infoset in regard to *input* so that it could solve his problem, i.e. being aware of CDATA section boundaries in the input XML. I don't think that's in the spirit of XSLT (or really of XML), but I'm not sure I can nail down why it *is* appropriate for XSLT to be CDATA-aware on output. Maybe it's an application of Postel's Law? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Postel#Postel.27s_Law

Comment: @LarsH: In order to be maximally useful, on input XSLT should accept as many data sources as possible. Ideally this is achieved if XSLT doesn't know anything about the lexical representation. In this way, for example, Michael Kay was able to process with XSLT non-XML genealogical data.

Comment: @LarsH: Serialization features belong to a diferent field. As example, you can output a DOCTYPE but DOCTYPE is not part of Infoset. One can argue that this distinction is not as clearly state in XSLT 1.0 as it's in XSLT 2.0 and XQuery (There is a separe spec about that).

Answer (score 2):

By the time the XSLT processor sees the text, the CDATA is gone.  You cannot see the incoming CDATA, and have very little control over how output CDATA is generated (all or nothing for a given tag).

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done in standard XSLT.

The input XML you're receiving,

```
<media:keywords>keyword1,keyword2<![CDATA[keyword3]]></media:keywords>
```

is indistinguishable (to XSLT) from

```
<media:keywords>keyword1,keyword2keyword3</media:keywords>
```

because the CDATA markup is just a way of escaping the data inside it. There is really no special markup to escape in this case, so the CDATA happens to be a no-op. But XSLT has no way of knowing what data was originally expressed using CDATA, what was expressed using character entities, etc.

The solution would be to tell whoever is providing this XML that they need to put a delimiter between keyword2 and keyword3.

Comment: @LarsH: indistinguishable not only to XSLT, but for every XML tree provider following specs for Infoset as @Dimitre've point out, or modern XDM.

Comment: @Alejandro: right (although an XML language/tool spec *could* use information about CDATA sections without actually violating the Infoset spec... see http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#conformance, 3rd bullet). I specified XSLT because the OP asked about an XSLT solution.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, an implementation could extend the Infoset, but the standar **explicity** say in http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#omitted : *The following information is not represented in the current version of the XML Information Set: 19. The boundaries of CDATA marked sections.*

Comment: @Alejandro: that info is omitted from the Infoset, but that does not necessarily mean that a tool (properly, the spec for a tool) "following specs for Infoset" cannot require info about CDATA marked sections, as long as it notes that additional requirement. That being said, this is only a haggle over wording of what it means to "follow" the Infoset spec. We agree that XML processors generally do not take notice of CDATA section boundaries, and should not be expected to (unless their spec says otherwise).

Comment: Turns out DOM is a good example of a tool that (AFAIK) follows the Infoset spec (at least wikipedia says DOM is an instance of Infoset, and the Infoset spec seems to imply it), but offers optional extensions to expose information about CDATA section boundaries. This was news to me... thanks @Dimitre.

Comment: @LarsH: technically, DOM follows its own specs. But there is a mapping http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/infoset-mapping.html